# Python Class not working as expected?

Tags: class, python-2.7

The code below is giving me the result "0" for Sunday.no_jobs, but there are 5 jobs on Sunday.

```
sunday = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sunday')

class Day:
    def __init__(self, day):
        self.day = day

    jobs = {}
    def getjobs(self, day): #populates a dictionary with the information from an excel sheet
       for i in range(start_row,day.nrows):
          self.jobs[i-1] = [str(day.cell_value(i,0)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,1)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,2)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,3)).upper(), str(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(day.cell_value(i,4),0)[3])+":"+str(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(day.cell_value(i,4),0)[4]), str(day.cell_value(i,5)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,6)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,7)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,8)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,9)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,10)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,11)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,12)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,13)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,14)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,15)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,16)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,17)).upper(), str(day.cell_value(i,18)).upper()]

    no_jobs = len(jobs)

Sunday = Day(sunday)

print Sunday.day

Sunday.getjobs(Sunday.day)

print Sunday.jobs[1][1]

print Sunday.no_jobs
```

This works if I do:

```
print len(Sunday.jobs)
```

How can I amend the class so that "print Sunday.no_jobs" would produce "5"?

Comment: Python and poor indentation is **not** a good mix. Can you edit your question so at least we'll know where the class body ends?

Comment: Fix your indentation. no_jobs have the length of empty jobs. Put no_jobs = len(jobs) after you init the jobs and have a correct values for them (like jobs = getjobs(Sunday);no_jobs = len(jobs) )

Comment: Sorry, error when pasting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your variables attributes of the class `Day` using the `self` keyword:

```
class Day:
    def __init__(self, day):
        self.day = day
        self.jobs = {}
        self.no_jobs = 0
    def getjobs(self): 
        """populates a dictionary with the information from an excel sheet"""
        for i in range(start_row, self.day.nrows): # note self.day
            ... # use self.jobs here
        self.no_jobs = len(self.jobs)
```

Alternatively, make `no_jobs` a property:

```
    @property
    def no_jobs(self):
        return len(self.jobs)
```